# Load external html (separate header and footer) before executing js file

Tags: javascript, html

I stuck into this problem. My separate header and footer only show after the data in js file is completely fetched. When the data is loading, I can see the input (search image) and another text input but I can't see the header and footer. Any suggestion for getting the header and footer first before executing js file?

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script> 
            $(function(){
              $("#header").load("../header/index.html"); 
              $("#footer").load("../footer/index.html"); 
            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../header/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../footer/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <section>
            <div>
                <input type="image" src="search.png" id="submitKeywordButton" onclick="submitKeyword();" />
                <div style="overflow: hidden;">
                   <input type="text" name="subscribe" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div id="footer"></div>
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Header file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
            <a href="../index.html"><img src="../img/icon.png" height="40" width="160"/></a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <img src="../img/firstFlag.png" height="20" width="30"/>
            <a href="./en.html"><img src="../img/secondFlag.png" height="20" width="30"/></a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: so.. your header and footer is in separate html and you used javascript to add the header or footer into the page? uh, definitely you will have your header or footer appear only after the entire page loaded.. your `main.js` is at the bottom of the page. so until the browser reached that, you wont see your header/footer.

Comment: Yea. Thinking any ways that can show the header and footer first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../header/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../footer/style.css">
</head>
<body style="display: none">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <section>
        <div>
            <input type="image" src="search.png" id="submitKeywordButton" onclick="submitKeyword();" />
            <div style="overflow: hidden;">
               <input type="text" name="subscribe" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>         
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(function(){
            $("#header").load("../header/index.html", function (){
                $("#footer").load("../footer/index.html", function() {
                    $("body").fadeIn(1000);
                }); 
            });                             
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Note* <body style="display: none">

Comment: this is a good idea, though it will mean that user only sees blank page when the pages load.

Answer (score 0):

if `load` method is sync, then try change your html structure like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../header/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../footer/style.css">
    <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="display: none">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script> 
       $("#header").load("../header/index.html"); 
       $("#footer").load("../footer/index.html"); 
    </script>
    <section>
        <div>
            <input type="image" src="search.png" id="submitKeywordButton" onclick="submitKeyword();" />
            <div style="overflow: hidden;">
               <input type="text" name="subscribe" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>        
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```